# h2o.relevel to set an increasing order of a factor in R H2O

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o

I used h2o.relevel to reorder the levels of a factor df$x. But, when I tried to get the min or max using h2o.which_min(df$x) and h2o.which_max, the output was: NAN. This tells me that h2o.relevel does not set a increasing order for instance.

Example:
x: factor w/4 levels "B" "D" "A" "C". df is the dataframe.

I tried this: With h2o.relevel(df$x, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), I'm able to rearrange the levels TO "A", "B", "C", "D", but A is not the minimum and D is not the maximum. h2o.which_min(df$x) and h2o.which_max return NAN.
How can I make A the min value and D the max value? Please help. Thank you

Comment: You'll get faster better answers if you include some minimal demo data + code that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1):

Enum (aka factor, aka categorical) in H2O are not ordinal.

So it's not possible to do comparisons in this way.

If you really want to do this, I recommend duplicating the column so that the original remains a factor and the duplicate is an integer.